# How to use Waterfox along with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, waterfox

I want to use both of them but they use the same profile. I wanted to make one for Waterfox but I realized Firefox will probably change. And I prefer not to execute it via parameter as profile since I want to launch Waterfox via taskbar (and to my knowledge you can't have parameters there, as you can with regular shortcuts).

To rephrase my question, I want them to be completely separate like how Chrome and Firefox would work side by side.

Thanks.

Comment: The closest I can think of is if you type 'firefox -p' into run you can configure profiles. If you uncheck the box that says 'Use selected profile.. at startup' when firefox starts it will ask you what profile to select.

Comment: Why do you think you can't have parameters when launching from the taskbar?

Comment: I stumbled back across this question and see that you never responded.  I launch "firefox -p" from the tray, which opens a profile selection dialog.  So it obviously can be done.  If you still need help with this, you'll need to provide more information on exactly what you're trying and the manner in which it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Portable versions of both browsers, because their profile folder is under the main folder, so it is independent.

But also u can copy the profile folder (\user) from one to the other and have it synchronized.
Waterfox 55 compatible with Firefox55 but also with older Firefox versions